# Merge query in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
     MERGE INTO temp d
USING (
        select lid,cid,eid,tid,eeid from 
        table where
        eid=5) s
ON (d.lid = s.lid and d.cid = s.cid and d.EID = s.EID and d.tid = s.tid and d.eeid = s.eeid)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (lid, EID,cid, tid, eeid, is_locked)
VALUES (s.lid, s.EID, s.cid, s.tid  s.eeid, (select nvl(min(is_locked),0) from (
        select ppl.is_locked, ROWNUM RNK
        from ppl
        where ppl.lid = s.lid and ppl.tid = s.id and ppl.cid = s.cid and ppl.eeid = s.eeid and ppl.eid = s.eid
        order by ppl.locked_dt desc
    ) where RNK = 1 ));
```

The select query im writing in values is saying s.eid and all other s references as invalid identifier

Can anyone provide a fix how I can use S inside values part.

Comment: whats that some select query?

Comment: Updated @eshirvana

Comment: as you don't have an update part, then rewrite it as just an insert ... where not exists ....

Comment: There is an update part... it was too big that's why I did not write it here

Answer (score 0):

you can prepare the values in advance:

```
MERGE INTO temp d USING (
    select lid,cid,eid,tid,eeid, ppl.is_locked
    from table 
    LATERAL  ( select nvl(min(is_locked), 0) is_locked
                from  ppl
                where
                        ppl.lid = d.lid
                        and ppl.tid = d.id
                        and ppl.cid = d.cid
                        and ppl.eeid = d.eeid
                        and ppl.eid = d.eid
                order by ppl.locked_dt desc
    ) ppl
where eid = 5) s 
ON (d.lid = s.lid and d.cid = s.cid and d.EID = s.EID and d.tid = s.tid and d.eeid = s.eeid)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (lid, EID, cid, tid, eeid, is_locked)
VALUES (s.lid, s.EID, s.cid, s.tid  s.eeid,s.is_locked);
```

you were returning first row  in your subquery then min() were not making sense , so I'm getting the min among all records , if you really wanted the first row , then you can change the sub query accordingly , but you got the idea